# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError: Element cannot be scrolled into view:[object HTMLSpanElement]

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

Something strange is happening on this page:

```
require "watir-webdriver"
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto "http://mideastunes.com/"
b.div(class: "feat-container").element(css: "a span").present?
 => true 
b.div(class: "feat-container").element(css: "a span").click

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError: Element cannot be scrolled into view:[object HTMLSpanElement]
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:64:in `request'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:590:in `raw_execute'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:568:in `execute'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:350:in `clickElement'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.19.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:34:in `click'
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@gretel/gems/watir-webdriver-0.5.3/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:107:in `click'
    from (irb):48
    from /Users/zeljko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

I am trying to click this span:

```
<span class="feature-prev-icon icon"></span>
```

I can click it with this:

```
b.span(class: "feature-prev-icon icon").click
```

but I would like to click it with this:

```
b.div(class: "feat-container").element(css: "a span").click
```

Environment: Mac OS X 10.7.3, Firefox 10.0.1, ruby 1.9.2p290, selenium-webdriver 2.19.0, watir-webdriver 0.5.3

Comment: I just got the same result on FF10 on Windows Vista Home Premium. This is an area that I am very weak in but I will try to learn more about it.

Comment: Issue is reproducible on Gentoo Linux, Firefox 10.0, ruby 1.9.2p290, selenium-webdriver 2.19.0, watir-webdriver 0.5.3

However, it's not watir-webdriver issue as long as the same error occurs with plain selenium-webdriver

`b.find_element(:css => "div.feat-container").find_element(:css => "a span").click`

Comment: Mine runs but it clicks a play button somewhere instead. watir-webdriver 0.3.9, selenium-webdriver 2.12.1 in Windows 7, Firefox 8.  So I'm a bit behind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: This isn't a bug.

As other answerers have indicated, the element you're interacting with is off-screen and can't be scrolled in to screen other than by complex interaction.

This probably does what you want:

b.div(class: "feat-container").elements(css: "a span")[2].click

What you probably want to do in this case is rather than checking:

b.div(class: "feat-container").element(css: "a span").present?

Looping over each child, checking that its bounding box is on screen, specifically in this case that the left coordinate is non-negative.

This is a bit unintuitive of WebDriver - unfortunately, there isn't really a good way to handle the underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks, I found that bug and I am already following it, but I was not sure if it was connected. I forgot to include it in the question.

Comment: Not so sure this bug is happening here.  From what I've seen, the element you're getting returned is genuinely outside of the page area that watir-webdriver can interact with.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem stems from what you're trying to click.

```
puts b.div(class: "feat-container").element(css: "a span").attribute_value("class")
```

returns

`play-icon play`

Which is the play button on a slide that has been 'hidden' off to the left using positioning and left:-ahugevalue

Watir-webdriver is not being buggy here, it's just telling you it can't click it as it can't scroll that far left as there's no horizontal scrollbar.

edit: by the way the system used to test this differs greatly to the one commented above.  I don't live in fear of breaking everything at home like I do at work.  Everything is up to date.  Firefox 10.0.1, Ruby 1.9.2, Watir-webdriver 0.5.3, Selenium-webdriver 2.19.0 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too.
There is also a [ticket](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3075).

The problem could be caused by a weird unscrollable layout, so the button could only be reached if the window was bigger.

So resizing the window, could fix it.

in java it was:

```
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, 0));
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1100, 800));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use to bring the element into view (and maximize the page):

```
page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize
```