# Trying to click a link in a dropdown which can only be accessed by hovering over an element

Tags: javascript, ruby, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to click on an element (link) in a drop down which only appears when hovering over an element. 
Unfortunately I cannot provide a link to the site where issue is occurring, as functionality is not available on our Live site yet. See below for the HTML code for which this issue concerns:

```
<li class="sub-menu">
  <span class="label">Signed in as</span>
  <span class="val">Xkeek Javed Wezacur</span>
  <a href="#user-actions">Menu</a>
  <ul id="user-actions">
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
      <a href="/sign_out">Sign out</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Now I am trying to access and click code:

```
<a>href="/sign_out">Sign out</a>
```

I have tried various solutions, but get errors everytime. See below for what I have tried and the errors I have received:

```
@browser.li(:class, 'sub-menu').ul(:id, 'user-actions').link(:text, 'Sign out').click
```

Element cannot be scrolled into view:https://xxxuat.com/sign_out (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError)

```
@browser.ul(:id, 'user-actions').link(:text, 'Sign out').click
```

Element cannot be scrolled into view:https://xxxuat.com/sign_out (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError)

```
@browser.link(:text, 'Menu').link(:text, 'Sign out').click
```

unable to locate element, using {:text=>"Sign out", :tag_name=>"a"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)

```
@browser.link(:text, 'Sign out').click
```

Element cannot be scrolled into view:https://xxxuat.com/sign_out (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError)

I have tried to find some answers using stackoverflow and Google groups, if I can be pointed in the right direction I would be very grateful. Thank you guys.

Environment: Mac OSX 10.7.5, Firefox 19.0.2, Ruby 1.9.3p194, watir-webdriver 0.6.2

I just tried:

```
@browser.link(:text, 'Menu').fire_event('onmouseover'),      
@browser.li(:class, 'sub-menu', :text, 'Sign out').link.click
```

The error I got was:
    expected Hash or (:how, 'what'), got [:class, "sub-menu", :text, "Sign out"]     (ArgumentError).
Now I am confused

Comment: If you can not link to the actual page, link to a similar page where the problem can be reproduced. If such page does not exist, create it.

Comment: A very similar question was answered here.  See if this helps.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270259/seleniumwebdrivererrormovetargetoutofboundserror-element-cannot-be-scroll

Comment: Thanks Bala, i'll look into it and if I solve my issue, i'll add my answer here.

Comment: For your ArgumentError, you need to pass in a hash if you want to use multiple locators. It should be `@browser.li(:class => 'sub-menu', :text => 'Sign out')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woohoo!!! Finally I got it working :). I had to manipulate the javascript to show the drop down, as every other method was failing, here is my code:

```
@browser.execute_script("$('#user-actions').css('left',0);")
@browser.link(:text => 'Sign out').when_present.click
```

Thank you Justin and Bala for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Watir will only click elements that are visible. Since the sign out link is only visible if the submenu is displayed, you need to first display the submenu.

The following works to expand the menu and then click the sign out link:

```
#Expand submenu
browser.ul(:id => 'account-menu').link(:text => 'Menu').click

#Click sign out
browser.link(:text => 'Sign out').click
```

Comment: Hi Justin, I tried your solution and I still get same error (Element cannot be scrolled......). Did your solution work for you?

Comment: Yes, it did work. I was doing it through irb, so my guess is a timing issue. For the last line, try `browser.link(:text => 'Sign out').when_present.click` instead.